# When populating a fact table storing counts hourly, should 0-count records be included?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I have a table which stores every call logs. I'm trying to ETL this into a fact table that aggregates the logs hourly.

```
Fact_CallLog
===============
dim_date_id(PK)
dim_time_id(PK)
call_type(PK)
call_result(PK)
call_count
```

I wrote this query to populate the fact table.

```
SELECT log_dim.dim_date_id
      ,log_dim.dim_time_id
      ,log_dim.call_type
      ,log_dim.call_result
      ,COUNT(*) call_count
FROM [DW_Source_CTI].[dbo].[OLD_cti_call_log] log
LEFT JOIN (
      --categorize each call log with date, time, call type, call result
) log_dim ON log.cid = log_dim.cid
WHERE ~~~ --exclude faulty call logs
GROUP BY log_dim.dim_date_id
        ,log_dim.dim_time_id
        ,log_dim.call_type
        ,log_dim.call_result
```

Problem is, this query can't populate records when there was no call. For example, if call logs of certain period was like below,

```
12AM  3 calls
1AM   0 call
2AM   1 call
```

then records from 1AM will not be populated on `Fact_CallLog`.

My question is, should I insert these not populated records with `call_count = 0`? Or not?

Comment: 1. Do you need them? 2. If you include them what proportion of records will they be? 2%? 20%. You can always make these appear in subsequent reporting steps by outer joining to an 'hour' table. It depends on your reporting requirements and whether it makes your logic substantially easier to include them.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid 1. At least I think so. I'm using DW for data mining purpose and I'm trying to forecast 'how many calls will be made for each time period'. Therefore `call_count = 0`is important since it has information when calls is not happens.

Comment: If your data mining tool needs this record (almost certainly yes) then there's your answer!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Oh, it was simple as that :D Just to be clear, I was not sure whether this `call_count = 0` records should be generated everytime I needed or these records should be in the fact table early on.

Comment: Well there will be other constraints and requirements that will help you to make this decision. For example if you find that these are forming 80% of your records and you have some space constraints then that might indicate that you shouldn't put them in. On the other hand you might find that _not_ having these records causes you great difficulty/complexity in your data mining tool which means you should put them in. Generally speaking I would say if they aren't too high a proportion of records (say 10%) then put them in.

Comment: One of the purposes of a dimensional model is to make your querying easier by performing complex logic earlier in the ETL process, so don't be afraid of putting helper records like this in. You just need to rethink it if they are taking up a lot of space and causing space / performance issues

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks alot! If your comments were an answer, I'd accept it immediately

Comment: No worries :) good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have them, there is probably no need to put them in the table.  But, if you want/need them there, then run the query like:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM log_dim LEFT JOIN
     [DW_Source_CTI].[dbo].[OLD_cti_call_log] log
     ON log.cid = log_dim.cid AND
         ~~~ --exclude faulty call logs
. . .
```

That is, start with the `log_dim` for the `LEFT JOIN` and then move the `WHERE` conditions to the `ON` clause.